# AWS Boto3 and Classic ELBs

Tags: boto, boto3, elastic-load-balancer, botocore

I'm trying to get the active TLS policy on a classic load balancer (elb, not elbv2) and I'm having trouble identifying what is going wrong here:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

#Declare Constant
EXPECTED_POLICY = 'ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-1-2017-01'
IAMID = '518031149234'

def set_session(awsprofile, awsregion):
    try:
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=awsprofile, region_name=awsregion)
        return session
    except ClientError as e:
        print("Failed to run session setter for profile: {0} %s" % e).format(awsprofile)

def assume_role_into_account(profileId, assumeId, sessionName, assetType, regionName):
    try:
        setSession = set_session(profileId, regionName)
        stsSession = setSession.client('sts')
        response = stsSession.assume_role(RoleArn=("arn:aws:iam::{0}:role/security").format(assumeId),RoleSessionName=sessionName)
        credentials = response['Credentials']
        session = setSession.client(assetType, aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'])
        return session
    except ClientError as e:
        print("AssumeRole exception for profile: {0} %s" % e).format(profileId)

def main():

    try:
        srev2 = assume_role_into_account('sre', IAMID,'Security-Audit-AssumeRole-Session2', 'elb', 'us-east-1')
        print("AssumeRole into Account: {0} for Region: {1} .").format(IAMID, 'us-east-1')

    elbs = srev2.describe_load_balancers()

    for elb in elbs:
        policy = session.describe_load_balancer_policies(LoadBalancerName=elb)

    except ClientError as e:
        print("AssumeRole: Cannot assumerole for id: {0}." % e).format(IAMID)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So when I return policy when calling `describe_load_balancer_policies()`, there is no way to distinguish which policy is selected.

Any help?

TIA!

Comment: Using Boto3 version 1.4.4 if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a long discussion with the API and ELB team folks at Amazon... here is what we came up with, note this is only for classic ELB's. This will indeed return the ELB Policy you see in the AWS Web Console, every time.

I spent a lot of time on this and i hope it benefits someone else that has also looked into this time-suck, near-fruitless endeavor:

```
elbs = client.describe_load_balancers()

for elb in elbs:
    #Get Named Policy to pass to get the active policy. -1 denotes the last in the list.
    policy_name = jmespath.search('ListenerDescriptions[].PolicyNames[] | [-1]', elb)

    policy_description = client.describe_load_balancer_policies(LoadBalancerName=elb, PolicyNames=[policyname])
    console_policy = jmespath.search('PolicyDescriptions[?PolicyName==`{0}`] | [0].PolicyAttributeDescriptions[0].AttributeValue'.format(policyname), policy_description)

    return console_policy
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help if you don't paste the related error message.

From a quick view, I guess you define local variable `session` in `assume_role_into_account` which can't be accessed in `main()`

If this is the problem, you can change it to

```
def assume_role_into_account(profileId, assumeId, sessionName, assetType, regionName):
  global session
  ....
```

Refer:

[Python - Global, Local and nonlocal Variables](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)

Comment: I'm not getting an error message, i'm getting identical results from two different policies. As in, i have nothing to filter on. Even position in the dict varies from elb to elb.